# How to call onsnapshot firebase result from other file/module?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know if it's possible to return the value of onSnapshot from one file to another, maybe the example helps.

This is my firebase-dishes-crud.js file

```
    const listenRealTimeDishes =  () => {
     firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("dishes")
      .onSnapshot((dishes) => {
        let dishesAux = [];
        dishes.forEach((dish) => {
          dishesAux.push({ id: dish.id, ...dish.data() });
        });
        return dishesAux;
      });
  };
```

And this is in  my dishes-list.js file.

```
  const [dishes, setDishes] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
  setDishes(dishesCrud.listenRealTimeDishes());}
  ,[]);

return (
<ul>
 {dishes.map((dish)=>(
  <li>{dish.price}</li>
)}
</ul>
)
```

Obviously it does not work, but I want to know if there is way to achieve something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return data that is asynchronously loaded. The call to `setDishes` must happen from within the `onSnapshot` callback.

One simple way to do this is to pass along that callback to your `listenRealTimeDishes` function:

```
useEffect(() => {
  dishesCrud.listenRealTimeDishes(setDishes));
},[]);
```

And then call it from there:

```
  const listenRealTimeDishes = (setDishes) => {
     firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("dishes")
      .onSnapshot((dishes) => {
        let dishesAux = [];
        dishes.forEach((dish) => {
          dishesAux.push({ id: dish.id, ...dish.data() });
        });
        setDishes(dishesAux);
      });
  };
```